# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^nf(x)+g(x)}{x^n+1}$,$x\in R$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^nf(x)+g(x)}{x^n+1}$,$x\in R$

As $x\in R$.Split it into 4 cases,$|x|<1,|x|>1,x=1,x=-1$
When $|x|<1$,$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^nf(x)+g(x)}{x^n+1}=g(x)$,
When $|x|>1$,$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^nf(x)+g(x)}{x^n+1}=f(x)$,

When $x=1$,$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^nf(x)+g(x)}{x^n+1}=\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2}$

When $x=-1$,$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^nf(x)+g(x)}{x^n+1}=$not defined.

I understood first three cases,but the fourth case when $x=-1$,i did not understand.Why the limit is not defined when $x=-1$.Please help me.

Comment: because the value of the denominator oscillates between 0 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^nf(-1)+g(-1)}{(-1)^n+1}$$
Notice that $(-1)^n$ oscillates between $1$ and $-1$... as a result, how we know if the answer is positive or negative as we approach infinity? Further, whenever $n$ is odd the denominator is $0$, making the function undefined. Thus, the limit is undefined for all odd $n$ and thus has no limit as ${n \to \infty}$. 
(Note: If you exclude all odd, integer values of $n$ though the limit does exist when $x=-1$)